# In jQuery how do you check and uncheck all checkboxes using an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code. It checks all the checkboxes on the page using the LABEL element which is usually on top of the checkboxes. Now how do I use the same LABEL element to uncheck all the boxes?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 var $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

 $('label').click(function() {
   $checkBoxes.attr('checked', true);
 });
});
```

Comment: what happens when some(not all) of the checkboxes are checked - would you check all or uncheck all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: +1 excellent.this is what i am searching for

Answer (score 3):

For toggling, you need to store the state somewhere, like in `data()` :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $('label').on('click', function() {
        var check = !$(this).data('checked');
        $checkBoxes.prop('checked', check);
        $(this).data('checked', check);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CtX6K/1/)

Comment: In most systems I've used, the "check-all" element is also a checkbox, so you can just use its `:checked` state to save the value.

Comment: @Barmar - in this case the OP has only stated that it's a label, and not if it contains a checkbox or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
var checked = 0;

$('label').click(function() {
   if(checked) {
       $checkBoxes.prop('checked', true);
       checked = 1;
   } else {
        $checkBoxes.prop('checked',false);
        checked = 0;
   }
 });
```

Comment: [Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked ...](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

Comment: @zeroflagL Indeed thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

This code should work (not tested):

```
$checkBoxes.prop('checked', $checkBoxes.not(':checked').length ? true : false);
```

---

After a second reading, im not sure if that's what you want. Do you want a "checkall" button so when you click on it, if 1 or more checkboxes is unchecked, it check all else uncheck all or really a "toggle button"?

Answer (score 0):

All `on` or all `off`.  Plus a closure to keep it all tightly scoped.

```
$('label').click((function () {

   var state = false;

   return function () {
      $checkBoxes.prop('checked', state = !state);
   };
}()));
```