# Setting and unsetting an attribute works only once

Tags: jquery

I have a form with several checkboxes that I'm trying to check/uncheck by clicking certain links. It works the first time I use it, but then fails every time there after. Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Checkbox Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#chkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
        $('#unChkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Checkbox Test</h2>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0">
            Checkbox</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1">
            Checkbox</label>
        <br>
    </p>
</form>
<p><span id="chkAll">Check All</span> / <span id="unChkAll">Uncheck all</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what going on here. When I inspect the input element using firebug, it shows the "Checked" attribute being set and unset. Yet, when actually looking at the checkboxes, nothing changes.

Help is required.

Comment: That's because you should be setting the property with prop(), not the attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery how do you check and uncheck all checkboxes using an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457818/in-jquery-how-do-you-check-and-uncheck-all-checkboxes-using-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working after first time as you've described is because you're using `.removeAttr()` so it'll permanently remove your `checked` attribute from all the checkboxes.

So, in your case you want to set it instead of removing it, that's why you should use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.removeAttr()`:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#chkAll').click(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('#unChkAll').click(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y47Vf/)**

Answer (score 1):

use `.prop`

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        $('#chkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
        $('#unChkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
        });
    });
```

Learn more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.removeAttr()` which removes an attribute from element:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        $('#chkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
        $('#unChkAll').click(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/qf3E7/)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I've seen other answers where people were trying to do the same thing and that's where I picked up the 'attr' tjhing.

Comment: @TomHarger: Hope this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery